# Bug in Neural Network with cost function rising

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, activation-function

I have been working on my first neural net, building it completely from scratch. However when printing the cost function to track the models progress it only rises, the data I am using is just 1s,0s I wanted something simple for my first model. It has one hidden layer of two tanh nodes and then outputs into a sigmoid unit.

Code is below, copied from markdown version of jupyter notebook:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```py
#creating our data
x = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
y = y.reshape(1, 4)
```

```py
print(x)
```

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

```py
print(y)
```

```
[[0 1 0 1]]
```

```py
print(x.shape)
```

```
(5, 4)
```

```py
print(y.shape)
```

```
(1, 4)
```

```py
#initalize parameters
def rand_params():
    W1 = np.random.randn(2, 5)
    b1 = np.zeros([2, 1])

    W2 = np.random.randn(1, 2)
    b2 = np.zeros([1, 1])
    
    return W1, b1, W2, b2

W1, b1, W2, b2 = rand_params()
```

```py
print(f"W1: {W1}, b1: {b1}")
print(W1.shape, b1.shape)
```

```
W1: [[ 0.60366603 -0.12225707 -0.44483219 -1.40200651 -3.02768333]
 [-0.98659326 -0.91009808  0.72461745  0.20677563  0.17493105]], b1: [[0.]
 [0.]]
(2, 5) (2, 1)
```

```py
print(f"W2: {W2}, b2: {b2}")
print(W2.shape, b2.shape)
```

```
W2: [[0.05478931 0.99102802]], b2: [[0.]]
(1, 2) (1, 1)
```

```py
#forward propogation 
def tanh(z):
    a = (np.exp(z) - np.exp(-z)) / (np.exp(z) + np.exp(-z))
    return a 

def sigmoid(z):
    a = 1 / (1 + np.exp(z))
    return a 

def der_tanh(z):
    a = 1 - (tanh(z))**2
    return a 

def der_sigmoid(z):
    a = sigmoid(z) * (1 - sigmoid(z))
    # return a <-- MISSING?
```

```py
#forward computation
def forward_prop(x, W1, b1, W2, b2):
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, x) + b1
    A1 = np.tanh(Z1)

    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    y_hat = sigmoid(Z2)
    return Z1, A1, Z2, y_hat

Z1, A1, Z2, y_hat = forward_prop(x, W1, b1, W2, b2)
```

```py
def cost_function(y, y_hat, x):
    m = x.shape[1]
    J = -1 / m * np.sum(y * np.log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_hat))
    
    return J, m

J, m = cost_function(y, y_hat, x)
```

```py
#back propogation
def back_prop():
    dZ2 = y_hat - y
    dW2 = 1 / m * np.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    dZ1 = np.dot(W2.T, dZ2) * der_tanh(Z1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * np.dot(dZ1, x.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    
    return dW2, db2, dW1, db1

dW2, db2, dW1, db1 = back_prop()
```

```py
#optimizing weights + biases
def update(W1, b1, W2, b2):
    lr = 0.01
    W1 = W1 - lr * dW1
    b1 = b1 - lr * db1

    W2 = W2 - lr * dW2 
    b2 = b2 - lr * db2
    
    return W1, b1, W2, b2
    
W1, b1, W2, b2 = update(W1, b1, W2, b2)
```

```py
# model 

costs = []
W1, b1, W2, b2 = rand_params()


for epoch in range(1500):
    Z1, A1, Z2, y_hat = forward_prop(x, W1, b1, W2, b2)
    
    J, m = cost_function(y, y_hat, x)
    
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(J)
    costs.append(J)
    
    dW2, db2, dW1, db1 = back_prop()
    
    W1, b1, W2, b2 = update(W1, b1, W2, b2)
    
plt.plot(costs)
```

```
0.8188282199860928
1.1665507761146539
1.6868025884074527
2.3940967534280753
3.2473658397522387
4.183790888527539
5.158135855432985
6.147978715339146
7.143956636487831
8.142392777023431
9.141860280152706
10.141802197682296
11.142002210070622
12.142384342966537
13.142939005842882
```

Comment: I am aware about the cost function was just an error from a trial, regardless it does not change anything once fixed. Could you expand on the update function. where do I not declare it, its calculated and then returned. What do you mean by declaring it. The "magnitude of each step" is just the learning rate right, is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: THAT WORKED! thank you so much I feel so stupid such a basic function hahaha thank you so much for your help!

Comment: sorry it took so long done now, didn't realize I had to do that

Comment: Isn't there a missing `return a` in `der_sigmoid(z)`? - I added it as a comment in the code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apart from any other possible bugs, sigmoid(z) should be defined as:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    a = 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))
    #                 ^
    return a
```